# Changing position of characters in a string separated by commas

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have the following string, separated by commas and ";" must reverse the comma separated values ​​of all string delimited by ";".

Example:

```
-7.820420745913251,-38.221914235592905;-7.838209448558699,-38.206725420257172;-7.90608019095979,-38.238334576496392;-7.905396010088811,-38.163485189211315;-7.929205504398873,-38.168137619133972;-7.940015562160337,-38.155001346411183;-7.940973415379707,-38.154590837888591;-7.941520760076489,-38.154180329366007;
```

Result:

```
-38.221914235592905,-7.820420745913251;-38.206725420257172,-7.838209448558699;...
```

Help me, please!!

Comment: Is it a one huge string literal(value of a one column) or there are several of them?

Comment: ..and is it a one time thing? If so can you use for example excel?

Comment: Easy, normalize your table.

Comment: Assuming that this is how data is stored and you aren't allowed to change that (or can't afford it at this time), SQL was not designed with arrays or string manipulation in mind. Even if you come up with a way to do this, it'll possibly break badly when you encounter slight variations on the format (or plain invalid data). If you're consuming this with some other client language (C, Java, PHP...) it'd be faster and more reliable to retrieve data as is and manipulate it in that other language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(
'-7.820420745913251,-38.221914235592905;-7.838209448558699,-38.206725420257172;-7.90608019095979,-38.238334576496392;-7.905396010088811,-38.163485189211315;-7.929205504398873,-38.168137619133972;-7.940015562160337,-38.155001346411183;-7.940973415379707,-38.154590837888591;-7.941520760076489,-38.154180329366007;',
'([^,]*),([^;]*);','\2,\1;') RESULT
  FROM dual;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-38.221914235592905,-7.820420745913251;-38.206725420257172,-7.838209448558699;-38.238334576496392,-7.90608019095979;-38.163485189211315,-7.905396010088811;-38.168137619133972,-7.929205504398873;-38.155001346411183,-7.940015562160337;-38.154590837888591,-7.940973415379707;-38.154180329366007,-7.941520760076489;
```

See the [REGEXP_REPLACE documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm) for more information.

Comment: Friend, thank you very much for your help, solved all my problems!
I do not know how to thank you!